# Can we make a theoretical-physics tag?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Capturing theoretical-physics crowd with Research Level Tag](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1203/capturing-theoretical-physics-crowd-with-research-level-tag)

Since the site closed, perhaps we can revive its usefulness by adding a "theoretical physics" tag and adding it to all questions which would be suitable for that site. This is already so for astronomy. This will make a defacto subset of the problems screenable for professionals, who will be put off by the elementary questions.

This is not a "layman" tag, but the opposite.

Comment: Note that [astronomy] is a legit tag, whereas [TP] is a meta-tag. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/ Though I think we're keeping [research-level]

Comment: Yeah, we're already doing this as described in the linked question. As Manishearth said, [tag:astronomy] is not used to designate the questions which came from Astronomy.SE, it's used to designate questions which are about astronomy. So it's not true that we are already doing this for Astro.

Comment: No, this is no duplicate, because **theoretical** physics ≠ **research-level** physics. If one is interested, then I can explain what is the difference on both sides. Please, reopen the thread.