# Can we make a "new idea" tag possible duplicates

Tags: discussion

Possible duplicates:
 [Capturing theoretical-physics crowd with Research Level Tag](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1203/capturing-theoretical-physics-crowd-with-research-level-tag)
Also
[Can we make a theoretical-physics tag?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1281/can-we-make-a-theoretical-physics-tag)

Cane we capture the I was reading or I was watching a video and question crowd with a "new idea" tag

Comment: Argus, if you have the same question (about the [tag:research-level] tag) that was already asked twice, why would you ask it again?

Comment: This time I got the word correct. Someone who's is only knowledgeable in one are reads an article for the first time and wants task if a part of their are of expertise can give a new insight. A fresh pair of eyes so to speak.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying... could you explain it differently?

Comment: I will try say you are a thermodynamic student and a certain equation looks familiar but you just thought it should look a little different and that happens to be an particlephysics equation and you want to ask if I use tsomething from thermodynamic that I can make more sense with can thus improve the current idea.

Comment: So not a full fledged theory just a sought clarafication for someone with only basic knowledge in that expertise.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky: or even "aspiring-student" tag that might fit a little better

Comment: I still don't think I exactly understand what you're asking, sorry... but I don't see that there's any need for a tag like that. (Nothing wrong with suggesting it, though!)

Comment: It would cover any questions that do not perfectly fit with the accepted general ideas for that subject. Andthank you for the consideration.