# Does physics.SE help research?

Tags: discussion, content-level

Does some *concrete* evidence exist that the physics.SE site offers any help with research? (Note that research in physics [may not be confused with theoretical physics, that is a specific thing](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6081/56960).) Were new works published there that later obtained recognition from the professional scientific community? Did anybody obtain key insights that prompted his/her research to succeed? Or, possibly, some in-deep reviews of pre-existing papers and textbooks did arise from discussions?

Comment: Yes, in my case, several great insights from posts and individuals here have assisted me in completing my current research in applied atmospheric physics

Comment: @Sabre Tooth: is it published now? If it is, then are contributions from SE acknowledged there?

Comment: Related question on MO.SE: https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/617/13917 . Discussion on how to cite Math.SE: https://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/4259/11127 and links therein.

Comment: @Qmechanic as a marginal note: physics.SE naturally evolved from unorganized SE crowd, whereas MathOverflow was originally a separate project, designed and managed by scientists from its onset. Ī do not expect *great achievements* from SE-created sites, but it would be interesting to learn about *some* achievements, presumedly comparable to efforts spent by participants.

Comment: To elaborate on QMechanic's links, the [Best of MathOverflow](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/617/best-of-mathoverflow) thread currently has 21 answers detailing publications inspired on, based on, or citing, MO questions and answers, including a number of collaborations that started on MO and who have never met in person. But MO was born into a much higher level than P.SE.

Comment: Even if it doesn't help you directly, it will help many of your students, so you need to spend less time on educating them.

Comment: Examples: https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.10553